# I found a bug in Java Puzzlers VI - can someone explain it?

Tags: java

Take a look at this [java puzzles vid](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/index.html#_java_puzzlers) by Josh Bloch and William Pugh, around time index 0:25:00-0:33:00.

One of the speakers says that if you use lowercase `boolean` instead of `Boolean`, then `LIVING` will be treated as a true "compile time constant", and it no longer matters when it is initialized.

Well, this is all fine and dandy, but, take a look at what happens when you revert to the original order between the static init and the constructor, and then follow it up by a simple "Extract Method" operation. These two programs print different outputs:

```
public class Elvis {
    private static final Elvis ELVIS = new Elvis();

    private Elvis () {}
    private static final boolean LIVING = true;
    private final boolean alive = LIVING;
    private final boolean lives () {return alive;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ELVIS.lives()); // prints true
    }
}
```

And with the refactored `returnTrue()` method

```
public class Elvis {
    private static final Elvis ELVIS = new Elvis();

    private Elvis () {}
    private static final boolean LIVING = returnTrue();

    private static boolean returnTrue() {
        return true;
    }

    private final boolean alive = LIVING;
    private final boolean lives () {return alive;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ELVIS.lives()); // prints false
    }
}
```

Why does extracting the returnTrue() method change the program output in this case?

Comment: Are you saying there are bugs in a bug/video about bugs? i think its called recurrence and you can get stackoverflow(but you are already on stackoverflow) :|

Comment: +1 - I didn't know the answer. I forwarded to someone who does.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The key to the behavior that you're observing is notion of "constant variable."  This oxymoron is defined in [JLS 4.12.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.4) as a variable of primitive type or type String that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression.  In [JLS 13.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#13.1), it says that references to constant fields are resolved at compile time to the constant values they denote (i.e., they're inlined). The puzzle in the video relies on the fact that a Boolean is neither a primitive nor a String. Your variant relies on the fact that invoking a method (returnTrue) in an expression prevents it from being a compile-time constant expression.  Either way, LIVING is not a constant variable and the program displays the counterintuitive behavior.

Puzzle 93 in Java Puzzlers ("Class Warfare") is related, and even more surprising.

Comment: Puzzle 39 or 93? The ["Class Warfare"](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/032133678x/advanced-puzzlers/ch10lev1sec8) is listed as 93.

Comment: Wait a minute. Is this the real Josh Bloch? Did you create an account just to answer this question?

Comment: Apparently, since he knows his stuff. How more authoritative can your answer be :)

Comment: I didn't exactly create an account; I just entered my name. But I am the "real" Josh Bloch. And yes, "Class Warfare" is Puzzler 93, not 39. Ooops.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't love Stack Overflow enough. Great video btw, I love how you and William present each riddle and pretend not to know the answers.

Comment: @Josh Bloch I feel like Wayne and Garth from Wayne's World falling to their knees and chanting "We're not worthy!" :-)

Answer (score 5):

In the second case `LIVING` is initialized by the runtime expression, therefore it's not a compile-time constant any more, and its value is `false` at the time when `ELVIS` is constructed.